# Post variables to Google App Engine page via JQuery (JSON)

Tags: jquery, python, json, google-app-engine

I have developed this simple web typing game http://www.fastypingcontest.com, which relies on the Google App Engine, and I am now trying to store the results. 
To this end I have added this JQuery code to the index page

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ scoreJS: score, backSpacesJS: backspaces, lettersPerSecondJS: 0});
console.log(jsonData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "commit",
    'data': jsonData,
    'dataType': 'json',
    success: success
    });
```

here is an example of json I get

{"scoreJS":1356,"backSpacesJS":0,"lettersPerSecondJS":0}

The target Python page is correctly reached but when it comes to get the variables like this

```
_score = self.request.get('scoreJS',default_value=0);
print _score
```

I get the default values

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I change the data like this

```
'data': {
    'json': jsonData,
 }
```

And I look for json in the python code I do get the right json string.
Why does it work and the first attempt does not?

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be in 'json' key. Access it as follows:

```
logging.info(self.request.get('json'))
```

Or you can post your data as follows, note that over here jsonData should not be converted to a json string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "commit",
    'data': jsonData, //Assign directly
    'dataType': 'json',
    success: success
    });
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while writing the question, I have reworded it

Comment: Have you tried sending the data without JSON.stringify(ing) it?